# Is there a shortcut to rerun a command with arguments from last command (not cd, ls or echo)

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

Searching through passed Logfile with something like this:

```
cat /path/to/logfile | grep -iEw 'some-ip-address-here|correspondig-mac-adress-here'
```

This gives me all the passed log lines until now so I can see what has been. Now I also want to see what's going on so I need to exchange `cat` with `tail -f` giving me this:

```
tail -f /path/to/logfile | grep -iEw 'some-ip-address-here|correspondig-mac-adress-here'
```

Comment: Probably none that are shorter than `up-arrow`, `home key`, 3*`delete` and type `tail -f`.

Comment: home key does not work home key inserts a ~ maybe thats something i have change myself but i got used to it and don't wana miss it also in putty home button inserts a ~ and pressing 30 to 40 times left-arrow is definitly not short

Comment: Try `CTRL-a` instead of home key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `!!:*` to refer to all the words but the zeroth of the last command line.

`!!` refers to the previous command, `:` separates the event specification from the word designator, `*` refers to all the words but the zeroth.

This is from the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section of bash(1).

```
wieland@host in ~» cat foo | grep bar
bar
wieland@host in ~» tail -f !!:*
tail -f foo | grep bar
bar
```

You could also use quick substitution where `^string1^string2^` repeats the last command, replacing `string1` with `string2`:

```
wieland@host in ~» cat foo | grep bar
bar
wieland@host in ~» ^cat^tail -f
tail -f foo | grep bar
bar
```

Comment: what i use now is cat to tail !!:* and tail to cat !!:2-$

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to recall the previous line. Repeat if you want the line before, etc.
2. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to delete the word under the cursor, i.e. the command you want to replace.
4. Type the command you want to run now.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command.